# Get magento shipping amount from each ordered item

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get shipping and handling amount. I was trying the snippet code below but it's not working. I am successfully sending some data to third party API after the place order .

```
echo $item->getShippingAmount();
```

but if I tried with.

```
echo $order->getShippingAmount();
```

It works but it shows total of shipping amount of all orders, but conversely I want each single amount to be shown.

`item ordered * quantity`

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
$order->getShippingIncTax()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

**for magento2 :**

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
       echo $item->getShippingAmount();
}
```